# Best way to update value of an object inside mongodb object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

This is how I store each element in my mongodb collection.

```
{
  _id: 'iTIBHxAb8',
  title: 'happy birthday',
  votesObject: { happy: 0, birthday: 0 }
}
```

I made a very dirty work around which I am not at all proud of which is this...

```
//queryObject= {id,chosenvalue};
let queryObject = req.query;
let id = Object.keys(queryObject)[0];
let chosenValue = queryObject[id];
db.collection("voting")
            .find({ _id: id })
            .toArray((err, data) => {
                let { votesObject } = data[0];
                votesObject[chosenValue] += 1;
                data[0].votesObject = votesObject;
                db.collection("voting").replaceOne({ _id: id }, data[0]);
                res.redirect("/polls?id=" + id);
            });
```

So basically what this does is It gets the chosen value which may be "happy" or the "birthday" from the above example.

- Finding the complete object from the collection which matches the id.
- Incrementing the chosen value from the found object.
- Using replaceOne() to replace the previous object with the newly changed object.

I am incrementing the value inside chosen value by one everytime this piece of code executes.

This works perfectly fine but I want to know if there is any **way to directly update the chosen value** without all this mess. I could not find a way to do it else where.

Comment: use `update` function

Comment: I have tried using findOneAndUpdate if that's what you are specifying. I don't know if any other method exists. If it does then I am not sure how it works . Sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_update.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use mongoose [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)
It will be something like

```
const updateKey = "votesObject.$."+ chosenValue
let incQuery = {}
incQuery[updateKey] = 1

Model.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: id }, 
    { $inc: incQuery },
    { new : false }, 
    callback
)
```

Comment: Your answer is working very perfectly. I just changed updateKey to "votesObject."+chosenValue and it is working like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator.

Try something like this:

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": id
},
{
  "$inc": {
    "votesObject.birthday": 1
  }
})
```

This query will increment your field `birthday` in one.

Check mongo playground exaxmple [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2h7Aj-CeCPf)

Comment: You are very close and I was too. But here the chosen value is not specific it can be anything stored in a variable "chosenValue". this wont work when I try to do "votesObject."+chosenValue+"":1

Comment: As @Deepak Poojari posted, the solution is create the 'query object' and do the query. But I think ```$``` operator can't be used. By the way if it works is ok.